# What steps are needed to use this VB code in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to use the VB code from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/324703/two-way-link-between-excel-workbooks?answertab=active#tab-top) question in Excel 2013 and it is not working. I am not familiar with VB and am most likely missing a simple step.

```
Private Sub Workbook_TwoWayMatch(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range) 
If UCase(Sh.Name) = "sheet1" Or UCase(Sh.Name) = "sheet2" Then 
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        If UCase(Target.Parent.Name) = "SHEET1" Then 
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Target 
        Else 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Target 
        End If 
        Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End If 
 End If
End Sub
```

Using a new workbook with worksheets named Sheet1 and Sheet2 I have tried the following in Visual Basic:

- pasting the code into the object: ThisWorkbook
- pasting the code into the objects: Sheet1 (Sheet1) and Sheet2 (Sheet2)
- pasting the code into all 3 objects
- ensuring the workbook is saved as macro enabled
- ensuring the workbook security settings are set to trust access to the VBA object model and that macros are enabled

What do I need to do in order to get this code to run?

In response to Mat's Mug's suggestion:

I put the code in a standard module as you suggested, changed the procedure to Public and modified the range.  However, I still cannot get it to copy the values from the range on one sheet to the other.  The code looks like this now:

```
Public Sub Workbook_TwoWayMatch(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET1" Or UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET2" Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:J23")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If UCase(Target.Parent.Name) = "SHEET1" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:J23") = Target
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J23") = Target
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you telling it to run that sub. It can be run from a cell or on a worksheet_change event or another location.  It needs to be called somewhere.

Comment: I do not believe I am calling it anywhere right now.  The code above is all I have.  Based on the question where I found it, I thought it was a simple copy and paste job but I now see that is not the case.  Ideally I would like it to run anytime a cell changes.

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook` and `SheetX` objects are special "document" *class* modules; macros are easier exposed in *standard modules*, so instead of pasting it everywhere in there, add a new *code module* (.bas) and paste it there.

The easiest way to add a new code module is to right-click anywhere in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R) and select *Insert* > *Module*.

The next problem, is that the procedure is `Private`. "Private" means that any code that must see and call this procedure, must be in the same *scope* - i.e. in the same module. Make it `Public` and you'll be able to call it from anywhere.

The next problem, is the parameters. From the implementation it looks like `Sh` is expected to be a `Worksheet` object, and `Target` is a `Range` object: to run the procedure you will have to supply the parameters.

There are many ways to do this.

One of them is to bring up the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) and call it directly:

```
Module1.Workbook_TwoWayMatch Sheet42, Sheet42.Range("Z123")
```

Of course the actual parameters you'll pass will vary depending on what you're trying to achieve, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `UCase(Sh.Name) = "sheet1"` on line 2 will never happen.

Try changing those to `"SHEET1"` and `"SHEET2"`.

Comment: I tried that but it does hot have any effect.